# Buildbot GitPoller - how to configure GitPoller with password

Tags: git, buildbot

I never used GitPoller with buildbot before, but I would like to encorporate it.
So I have a repo that I access with username and password, so when I clone it, I use: `https://username@host.com/path/to/repo.git` And when I try to pull or push it asks me for a password. So I think that my problem lies in the authentication part.

So far as `repourl` I tried to use:
`username@host.com`
`https://username@host.com`
`https://username@host.com/path/to/repo.git`
`https://username:password@host.com/path/to/repo.git`
But none of them work. I always get the following response:

```
2015-09-08 16:42:13+1000 [-] while polling for changes
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot\util\misc.py", line 54, in start
        d = self.method()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot\changes\base.py", line 70, in doPoll
        d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.poll)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
        return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot\changes\gitpoller.py", line 147, in poll
        yield self._dovccmd('init', ['--bare', self.workdir])
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot\changes\gitpoller.py", line 299, in _dovccmd
        [command] + args, path=path, env=os.environ)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\utils.py", line 174, in getProcessOutputAndValue
        reactor)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\utils.py", line 28, in _callProtocolWithDeferred
        reactor.spawnProcess(p, executable, (executable,)+tuple(args), env, path)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 353, in spawnProcess
        return Process(self, processProtocol, executable, args, env, path)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_dumbwin32proc.py", line 195, in __init__
        raise OSError(pwte)
    exceptions.OSError: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

The computer has git and connection configured, and works when I pull from command line. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: This looks more fundamental than just the password. It looks like your git binary isn't found in the shell which searching the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidDean was right. Buildbot was unable to use git from the PATH even though it was correctly configured on the machine, but adding git bin as an argument for git poller fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid GitPoller *gitbin* modification in your buildbot master configuration by setting Git bin path (C:\Program files\Git\bin) in your Windows slave %PATH% *system* environment variable.

Custom gitPoller *gitbin* variable on master may be problematic if your master is configured with Windows + Linux slaves.